# Fluent NHibernate mapping to a SQL Server CHAR(10) ID column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

New to both NHibernate and Fluent NHibernate and I'm trying to resolve a performance problem in some inherited code caused by a conversion of a `CHAR(10)` column to `NVARCHAR`.

From SQL Profiler:

```
exec sp_executesql N'select mytestclas0_.LinkId as LinkId45_, 
   mytestclas0_.Href as Href45_, 
   mytestclas0_.LinkActive as LinkActive45_ 
from MessageLinks mytestclas0_ 
where mytestclas0_.LinkId=@p0',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000)',@p0=N'BzE2T48HMF'
```

You can see the ID coming in from NHibernate is cast as a `NVARCHAR`.

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [Href] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [LinkActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [LinkId] [char](10) NOT NULL
 )
```

The class file:

```
public class MyTestClass {
    public MyTestClass() {}

    public virtual string LinkId{ get; set; }
    public virtual string Href{ get; set; }
    public virtual bool LinkActive { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping file:

```
  public class MyTestClassMapping : ClassMap<MyTestClass> {
    public MyTestClassMapping() {
      Table("MyTable");

      Id(x => x.LinkId).Length(10);
      Map(x => x.LinkId);
      Map(x => x.Href);
      Map(x => x.LinkActive);
    }
  }
```

I have tried a number of different things with the datatype of the LinkId and the mapping file, including these mappings:

```
    Id(x => x.LinkId).CustomSqlType("char(10)");
    Id(x => x.LinkId).Length(10).CustomSqlType("char");
    Id(x => x.LinkId).CustomSqlType("char");
```

I'm looking for a pointer to an example or documentation that explains how to get the ID passed in by NHibernate cast to a `CHAR(10)`.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: On your mapping, "Id" and "Map" to the same property "LinkId"?

Comment: As far as i know it doesn't cause any problems but it does allow me to see LinkId in the debugger.  It's not that way in the production code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mapping should be like this (see the documentation [5.2.2. Basic value types](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-types-basictypes)):

```
Id(x => x.LinkId)      
  .CustomType("AnsiString")
  ...
  ;
```

NHibernate type for `char` (non unicode string) is `type="AnsiString"` for xml mapping. the above is the way how to do that in fluent.

See similar story here: [NHibernate Performance (Ansi String vs. Unicode String)](http://toddstechnonsense.blogspot.cz/2010/11/nhibernate-performance-ansi-string-vs.html)

*Side Note: I've never managed to specify length ... always it is generated by NHibernate varchar(8000), using MS SQL 2008 dialect...*

Comment: *I've never managed to specify length* -> because it doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 5):

NHibernate MsSql2000Dialect and following versions define AnsiString correctly, also supporting length etc.

But, the current implementation of the SqlDriver got a change last year, 
see https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3036 for details of the fix.

The code does now ignore the specified length and always uses the default. Default for AnsiString and some others is varchar(8000)

```
RegisterColumnType(DbType.AnsiString, SqlClientDriver.MaxSizeForLengthLimitedAnsiString, "VARCHAR($l)");
```

code from SqlDriver:
setting default:

```
protected static void SetDefaultParameterSize(IDbDataParameter dbParam, SqlType sqlType)
{
    switch (dbParam.DbType)
    {
        case DbType.AnsiString:
        case DbType.AnsiStringFixedLength:
            dbParam.Size = MaxSizeForLengthLimitedAnsiString;
            break;
```

Bugfix:

```
    // Used from SqlServerCeDriver as well
    public static void SetVariableLengthParameterSize(IDbDataParameter dbParam, SqlType sqlType)
    {
        SetDefaultParameterSize(dbParam, sqlType);

        // no longer override the defaults using data from SqlType, since LIKE expressions needs larger columns
        // https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3036
        //if (sqlType.LengthDefined && !IsText(dbParam, sqlType) && !IsBlob(dbParam, sqlType))
        //{
        //  dbParam.Size = sqlType.Length;
        //}

        if (sqlType.PrecisionDefined)
        {
            dbParam.Precision = sqlType.Precision;
            dbParam.Scale = sqlType.Scale;
        }
    }
```

This of cause means no matter what you specify, it will not matter at all for the parameters. One can argue if this change is a good thing or not, I guess it is not ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess, as I've used CustomSqlType, but not personally with char.

```
  Id(x => x.LinkId).Length(10).CustomSqlType("char(10)");
```

or you may have to drop the Length.

```
  Id(x => x.LinkId).CustomSqlType("char(10)");
```

Here is a simiar:

[Possible to use CustomSqlType with CompositeId?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527951/possible-to-use-customsqltype-with-compositeid)

Comment: I believe I tried that earlier but just verified:

Neither   `Id(x => x.LinkId).Length(10).CustomSqlType("char(10)");`
nor `Id(x => x.LinkId).Length(10).CustomSqlType("char");` work